# can i increment date using xpath?

Tags: xpath

i need to increment current date by 7 days and i'm wondering if it's possible to do that using a xpath function.

thanks !!

Comment: How is your date value formatted? Can you show some sample XML snipped and the desired result?

Comment: xpath is not designed for data processing. it's primarily just a selector. why do you need to do this using xpath?

Comment: i'm not using xml file, we are using application that allow us to retrieve data from pipeline. date format is "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Comment: @mykhal : i need to set dynamically notification date and i can only do it using xpath. another question, can we retrieve date using " bpws:getVariableData " ?

Comment: What language is your application written in? Maybe XPath is not the best choice if your data/application are not XML-based.

Comment: @OxA3: it's java based application that provide a xpath cammand handler.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible in **XPATH 2.0**.  There are a [**number of date functions**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#durations-dates-times).

```
current-date() + xs:dayTimeDuration('P7D')
```

Comment: unfortunately i'm not able to use this function.

Comment: worked for me in Orbeon forms 

Answer (score 0):

If your date is in some numeric format (CTIME, seconds since 1970 (32 bit int), or FILETIME, 100 nanosecond counts since 1601 (64 bit)) then incrementing time is easy.  Just add the correct number of seconds (or 100 nanosecond intervals) to the time.

You could convert your format to CTIME via the Java time function library, add the correct number of seconds (86,400 seconds in a day), and then convert it back to your string format, I suppose.   Probably not the worlds most efficient approach though.

Comment: it's not possible because we have server restart each sunday and once restarted the timeout is reset.

Comment: @achraf:  Sorry, I do not understand your point.  I am suggesting you get the current time.  In CTIME format.  Then add 86400 seconds for each day you want to walk forward in time.  Then convert that back to the format you need.  You would have to redo this calc every time you need it, since the current time is different each time.